# Eclipse Git : Pull one branch changes into another branch

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I am new to Git and branching concept and having difficulties with it. In my application, we have many branches like test1, test2 etc. I have requirement to pull changes from **test1** branch to **test2** branch and **test1** branch contains changes from multiple teams. I have checked-out **test2** branch from GIT and need to pull changes from **test1** but I am not sure how to do it as I don't want to impact existing local changes in my workspace. Can anyone guide me how I can pull changes from **test1** branch to **test2** branch through GUI (not using commands). I am using GIT perspectives in Eclipse. Thank you.

Comment: Check-out `test2` as local branch as you already done it, right-click the repository and choose _Pull..._ (_Pull..._, not _Pull_); in the _Pull_ dialog enter `test1` as _Reference_.

Comment: @howlger Thank you so much !!. I followed your steps and now i am able to pull test1 into test2 in my local workspace but when i synchronize repository, commit from test1 appears as outgoing changes for test2 , so is it okay? Is there any way to pull/merge test1 changes  to test2 remotely and then get test2 changes on my local ?

Comment: You have two `test2` branches. First you checked-out the remote `test2` branch which means you created a second, but local `test2` branch. In the local `test2` branch you pulled the changes from the remote `test1` branch. Now, you have to do a push to get your local changes from your local repository branch `test2` into the remote repository branch `test2`.